# How can I insert a row from datagridview to Database

Tags: c#, database, winforms, datagridview, insert

Is there a way to insert a row from datagridview to database in winforms ?

This is how I create my gridview:

```
        this.dataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows = true;
        this.dataGridView1.AllowUserToDeleteRows = true;
        var query = from fe in tm.RDP0 select fe;
        testList = query.ToList();
        dataGridView1.DataSource = testList.ToList();
```

This is how I add a new row to my dataGridview

```
        RDP0 newrow = new RDP0();
        newrow.NO = 1 + dataGridView1.Rows.Count;
        newrow.CUSTID = 1000 + dataGridView1.Rows.Count;
        testList.Add(newrow);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = null;
        dataGridView1.DataSource = testList;
```

After I filled the newly created empty row on the datagridview I want to insert it to my Database.

```
tm.SaveChanges();
```

because SaveChanges() -above- doesnt work.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

No more need help. I found the solution.

```
            int index = dataGridView1.Rows.Count;
            RDP0 newefes = new EFESRDP0();
            newefes.NO = Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value);
            newefes.CUSTID = Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[1].Value);

            newefes.IPADDRESS = Convert.ToString(dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[3].Value);
            newefes.USER = Convert.ToString(dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[4].Value);                

            db.RDP0s.InsertOnSubmit(newefes);
            db.SubmitChanges();
```

via Linq to Sql method